# Error Code 1 when I install an assembly in GAC

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, gac

What is the error ?

```
The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\gacutil.exe" /i D:\WDS\bin\Debug\WDS.dll /f" exited with code 1.
```

I am using VS 2010 and I run this on my post build event.

```
"$(FrameworkSDKDir)bin\gacutil.exe" /i $(TargetPath) /f
```

I found in some forum that I have to quote the **TargetPath** like that

```
"$(FrameworkSDKDir)bin\gacutil.exe" /i "$(TargetPath)" /f
```

But the error is still there.

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: No message from gacutil before that?  Try typing the same command line in the Visual Studio Command Prompt window.  It is the wrong version btw if you target .net 4.  And UAC elevation required.  And using the GAC on your dev machine should always be avoided.

Comment: @Hans, Thanks for your reply.
I did UAC elevation.
Why we should avoid using GAC on our dev machine?
Sorry about my ignorance !!!

Comment: The GAC is a deployment detail.  What did typing the command explicitly tell you?

Comment: When I delete this script in the post build event and build , it's ok. 
So I try to regenerate by putting the script there again.
It does not show any error now.
Thanks you Hans.

Ghee, I don't know what's going on but it's running smoothly now.

Comment: Btw, what do you mean by GAC is a deployment detail?
Can you elaborate more ? I don't know about GAC.

Comment: Why don't you ask a question about it?  Check for previous questions first.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar error.  Following Hans Passant's comment to the question, I discovered an access denied error.  Running Visual Studio as Administrator fixed the problem.